# CoreOS logs flooded with "Unknown permission status for class system"

Tags: selinux, coreos, auditd, journald

I am trying to debug an issue, and I was wondering if this rings a bell to anyone: My logs get flooded with

`audit: type=1107 audit(1479418315.344:1053): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 msg='Unknown class service exe="/usr/lib64/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?';`

This seems to happen whenever an SSH connection is initiated (and we have lots of them, servers talking to each other and maintaining tunnels, etc...)

I did `auditctl -D` to clear all the audit rules (just for testing which rule generates that), but it has no effect...

My experience with SELinux is limited, so I am not even sure what to look for in the first place...

Thank you!